# Spring Integration Error

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-integration

I am new to Spring and Spring Integration. I am trying to debug my code and added the following in log4j.xml

```
<category name="com.atomikos.jms.AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean" additivity="false">
    <priority value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="TRACECONSOLE" />
</category>
```

This outputs all the Connection logs to the console. What i noticed is I see the connection log(see below) being outputted continuously. What I want to know is, Is this ok or indication of an error? If this is an error or a problem where do I start looking?

```
2014-09-15 21:28:46,859 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:46,859 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:46,859 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:46,859 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:46,859 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:46,859 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:46,859 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:3,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:3,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:46,859 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:2,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:2,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:46,859 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:46,860 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:46,859 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:4,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:4,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:46,860 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:46,860 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:46,860 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:5,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:5,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:46,860 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:6,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:6,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:7,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:7,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:8,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:8,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:9,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:9,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,096 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:10,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:10,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,097 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:11,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:11,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,097 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,097 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,097 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:12,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:12,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,097 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:13,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:13,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,863 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,863 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,863 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,863 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,863 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,864 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,864 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,864 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,864 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,864 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:47,864 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:2,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:2,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,864 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:3,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:3,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,864 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:4,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:4,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,864 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:5,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:5,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:47,864 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:6,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:6,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:7,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:7,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:8,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:8,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:9,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:9,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,107 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,108 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:10,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:10,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:48,108 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,108 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,108 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': init...
2014-09-15 21:28:48,108 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:11,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:11,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:48,108 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:12,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:12,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:48,108 DEBUG [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection() returning ActiveMQConnection {id=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-4:13,clientId=ID:abhisheks-mbp.lan-65520-1410841229249-3:13,started=true}
2014-09-15 21:28:48,868 INFO  [AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean] AtomikosConnectionFactoryBean 'activemqJmsCf': createConnection()...
```

Comment: Kindly format your exception trace...

Comment: Looks like you can't connect to MQ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's OK. It just an INFO from your JMS Listener Container, which tries to retrieve messages from the queue constantly.

Comment: This is only a source of docs we support: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#namespace-errorhandler. If you are talking about in particular about JMS, then you need to consult Spring JMS Docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/integration.html#jms. This is exactly a foundation for Spring Integration JMS Channel Adapters.

Comment: In spring integration,  do we have comprehensive error handling mechanism like apache camel ( OnException Clause, Try-catch-finally mechanism in DSL, handle-continue mechanism, propogation of error globally.  I am evaluating Spring Integration and Camel for our requirements but It do not have similar functionality.  Do let me know if my understanding is incorret or  guide me where  can get some support in terms of document or sample implementation.

Comment: For those use-case you need to take a look into the Endpoint advises: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain. The `@MessagingGateway` can catch and process exceptions with its `errorChannel`. All the Inbound endpoints have an `errorChannel` functionality as well. Since one of the first class citizens in Spring Integration is a `MessageChannel`  abstraction, all the possible error handling scenarios can be implemented in the flow started from the mentioned error channel.